# Using $.get to import contents from specific divs on another page and insert them into 2 divs

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

External page from which I'd want to import data looks like this:

```
<div id="cont1">something</div>
<div id="cont2">something else</div>
```

I am using this code to get the contents:

```
$.get("page.html", function(data) {
  $("#container1").html(data);
  $("#container2").html(cont2);
});
```

It works but not quite right since it's importing the containers too. How can I import only contents, not containers?

Comment: I tried searching for "*jquery parse html*", "*jquery extract from $.get*", etc and turned up many answers here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331149/how-to-parse-returned-page-html-with-jquery-get, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551230/jquery-selectors-on-a-html-string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047670/creating-a-jquery-object-from-a-big-html-string ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract part of HTML document in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137811/extract-part-of-html-document-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.get()` callback is importing the containers too because the complete response `data` (which includes the two outer `<div>`s) is being set as `innerHTML`.

To append only the contents without their containers:

- Parse the *`data` html string* using jQuery

  ```
  const $data = $(data);
  ```
- Filter the two `div`s using their `#id`s

  ```
  $data.filter("#cont1")
  $data.filter("#cont2")
  ```

  **This is the tricky part!** If you try to extract the containers using `find()` as described in other linked questions, the extraction will fail silently as `find()` returns an *empty* jQuery collection here.

  ```
  $data.find("#cont1").length == 0 // true
  $data.find("#cont1").html() == undefined // true
  ```

  *This is because there's no root element present in `data`, both the `<div>`s are siblings to each other.*
- Copy their `innerHTML` contents to current document's containers

  ```
  $("#container1").html($data.filter("#cont1").html());
  $("#container2").html($data.filter("#cont2").html());
  ```

The following is a complete example of parsing inner content as outlined above. <sub>Please ignore all the testdouble's `td` calls, that's just there to prepare the test case to respond with a mock AJAX response when the `$.get()` call is received.</sub>

```js
// Stub AJAX reponse
td.when(td.replace($, "get")("page.html")).thenCallback(`
    <div id="cont1">
        <b>testdouble.js</b> (td.js)
    </div>
    <div id="cont2">
        <i>Mocking library for JavaScript tests</i>
    </div>
`);

// Test response parser
$.get("page.html", function(data) {
  const $data = $(data);
  console.log($data.find("#cont1").length); // 0
  $("#container1").html($data.filter("#cont1").html());
  $("#container2").html($data.filter("#cont2").html());
  console.log($("#containers").prop("outerHTML"));
});

td.reset();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Parse AJAX Response Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/testdouble@3.16.1/dist/testdouble.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="containers">
    <div id="container1"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had already resolved this but thank you for your answer anyway.